# cmds algorithm not able to handle infinity (inf) in the distance matrix

Tags: python, numpy

If the input type is 'distance' there can ve a scenario that the matrix X can contain inf which basically represents disconnected points of the graph which is a perfectly valid scenario but this "B = -0.5 * H @ D**2 @ H" is throwing error in that case . Could you please help me in handling this case?

```
def cmds(X, n_dim, input_type='raw'):
    """
    Classical(linear) multidimensional scaling (MDS)
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    X: (d, n) array or (n,n) array
        input data. The data are placed in column-major order. 
        That is, samples are placed in the matrix (X) as column vectors
        d: dimension of points
        n: number of points
        
    n_dim: dimension of target space
    
    input_type: it indicates whether data are raw or distance
        - raw: raw data. (n,d) array. 
        - distance: precomputed distances between the data. (n,n) array.
    Returns
    -------
    Y: (n_dim, n) array. projected embeddings.
    evals: (n_dim) eigen values
    evecs: corresponding eigen vectors in column vectors
    """

    if input_type == 'distance':
        D = X
    elif input_type == 'raw':
        Xt = X.T
        D = euclidean_distances(Xt,Xt)
        
    # Centering matrix
    H = np.eye(D.shape[0]) - np.ones(D.shape) / D.shape[0]

    # Double-center the distance matrix
    B = -0.5 * H @ D**2 @ H

    # Eigen decomposition
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(B)

    # Sorting eigenvalues and eigenvectors in decreasing order
    sort_indices = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
    evals = evals[sort_indices]
    evecs = evecs[:, sort_indices]

    # Selecting top n_dim eigenvectors
    evecs = evecs[:, :n_dim]

    # Projecting data to the new space
    Y = np.sqrt(np.diag(evals[:n_dim])) @ evecs.T

    return Y, evals, evecs
```

Since this is a perfenctly valid scenario that the if the 2 points are not connected the distances between them will be set to inf. But the code will fail when computing the centering matrix and eigen values. Please help me here to handle this scenario

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the modified code

```
def cmds(X, n_dim, input_type='raw'):
"""
Classical(linear) multidimensional scaling (MDS)

Parameters
----------
X: (d, n) array or (n,n) array
    input data. The data are placed in column-major order. 
    That is, samples are placed in the matrix (X) as column vectors
    d: dimension of points
    n: number of points
    
n_dim: dimension of target space

input_type: it indicates whether data are raw or distance
    - raw: raw data. (n,d) array. 
    - distance: precomputed distances between the data. (n,n) array.
Returns
-------
Y: (n_dim, n) array. projected embeddings.
evals: (n_dim) eigen values
evecs: corresponding eigen vectors in column vectors
"""

if input_type == 'distance':
    D = X
elif input_type == 'raw':
    Xt = X.T
    D = euclidean_distances(Xt, Xt)

# Check for inf values in the distance matrix
if np.any(np.isinf(D)):
    # Replace inf values with a large but finite value
    D[np.isinf(D)] = np.finfo(D.dtype).max

# Centering matrix
H = np.eye(D.shape[0]) - np.ones(D.shape) / D.shape[0]

# Double-center the distance matrix
B = -0.5 * H @ D**2 @ H

# Eigen decomposition
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(B)

# Sorting eigenvalues and eigenvectors in decreasing order
sort_indices = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
evals = evals[sort_indices]
evecs = evecs[:, sort_indices]

# Selecting top n_dim eigenvectors
evecs = evecs[:, :n_dim]

# Projecting data to the new space
Y = np.sqrt(np.diag(evals[:n_dim])) @ evecs.T

return Y, evals, evecs
```

This modified code checks for inf values in the distance matrix and replaces them with a large but finite value before computing the centering matrix and eigen decomposition. This ensures that the code will not fail when dealing with disconnected points in the graph.